# What are the specifications of a Snowflake server?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

When it comes to cluster sizes, the documentation states that, for example an XS cluster consists on 1 server. But I have been looking for the server specifications and I can't seem to find any documentation on this topic.

Answer (score 10):

For AWS snowflake, if you open the browser console in Chrome (F12) and run this SQL in the normal snowflake window:

```
SELECT 1/0;
```

you will get an error, the network responce for that message has too much information, but one part states the server EC2 instance type as

```
  "warehouseServerType" : "c5d.2xlarge",
```

which was an x-small

Comment: Ahh - good research!  And my uneducated guess was - close, but no cigar...

Comment: FYI, this answer has now been quoted in an academic paper - "Towards Cost-Optimal Query Processing in the Cloud" by Leis and Kuschewski.

Comment: Just check again today, and the field now shows `"warehouseServerType" : null` so that's good that this detail is no longer leaked (for them)

Comment: doesn't work anymore...

Comment: @lightweight yes, that what the Jan 26th comment is saying.

Answer (score 5):

There are no apparent publicly available specs for the `WAREHOUSE` building blocks, other that on AWS, the compute nodes are EC2 servers.  Most likely an 8-thread CPU, 30-40 GB RAM (higher on Azure), and maybe around 250GB SSD.  Something like m5d.2xlarge, but I'm only guessing.

Importantly, those figures stack up when increasing the `WAREHOUSE` size, making most storage bound queries running faster.