# Server specs of Virtual warehouse servers in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I know that Snowflake takes away the headache of managing servers and sizing with its Virtual WH concept, but I wanted to know the physical specs of each individual server that Snow flake uses as part of its Virtual Warehouses or VH clusters. Can someone help?

Comment: [Snowflake: Running Millions of Simulation Tests with Amazon EKS](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/architecture/snowflake-running-millions-of-simulation-tests-with-amazon-eks/)

Comment: There's no official documentation for the physical specs of each warehouse. In any case, this question seems to be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58973007/what-are-the-specifications-of-a-snowflake-server.

Answer (score 0):

There's no official documentation for the physical specs of each warehouse.

Part of Snowflake's goal is to keep each warehouse performance equivalent throughout the 3 supported clouds. The specific hardware used for each instance will keep changing as Snowflake works to optimize users' experience and the offers of each platform.

[image]

- https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/warehouses-overview.html

In any case, this question seems to be a duplicate of [What are the specifications of a Snowflake server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58973007/what-are-the-specifications-of-a-snowflake-server).